# What is the most powerful events in the universe?

Tags: star, stellar-astrophysics

Is this idea disproved these days, please? What are the most powerful events in the universe?

> The evolution of hot stars usually ends as core-collapse supernovae,
> the most powerful and incredibly luminous events in the universe.

Comment: What is the source of the quote please.

Comment: It is a wrong statement. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It might be a useful statement, please tell the source of the statement

Comment: I wrote that and made mistake in that. It is not a quote. I used inappropriate text format.

Comment: See the "orders of magnitude (power)" wikipedia page at the following link.  It's a fun read!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(power)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black hole merger can be more powerful.

Power is energy divided by time, and energy can come in many forms. So the most powerful events are short, and might not be very hot or bright.

A powerful (type II) supernova might emit $10^{46}$ joules over 10 seconds. giving a power of $10^{45}$ watts. Most of this is in the form of neutrinos, with about 1% converted into light and heat.

By contrast, the merging black holes of GW150914 had [a peak power of $3.6×10^{49}$ watts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole), 36000 times more than the supernova, over a very short period of time (milliseconds). This was all in the form of gravitational waves, and there was no detected light given off. That is greater than the light power of every star in the observable universe combined.